# Codeigniter 3 application bug: converting title to slug does not work if there are diacritics in the title

Tags: codeigniter, diacritics

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

The single post URL is made from the post's title with `url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE)`. The entire post crearing function is this:

```
public function create() {

    // Only logged in users can create posts
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        redirect('login');
    }

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['tagline'] = "Add New Post";

    if ($data['categories']) {
        foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) {
            $category->posts_count = $this->Posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
        }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Short description', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/create-post');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        // Create slug (from title)
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
        $slugcount = $this->Posts_model->slug_count($slug, null);
        if ($slugcount > 0) {
            $slug = $slug."-".$slugcount;
        }

        // Upload image
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/posts';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $post_image = 'default.jpg';
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }

        $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image, $slug);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_created', 'Your post has been created');
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I was convinced it worked fine, until I added a post that had diacritics in its title. "La mulți ani România!" results in the slug *la-mul??i-ani-rom??nia* instead of *la-multi-ani-romania*.

I tried to fix thos issues with Codeigniter's `convert_accented_characters()`:

```
$slug = convert_accented_characters(url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE));
```

It does *not* work even thou I *did* load the test helper:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'date', 'text');
```

What other options do I have? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which I used the `url_title()` and `convert_accented_characters()` was wrong.

This is the **correct** one:

```
$slug = url_title(convert_accented_characters($this->input->post('title')), 'dash', TRUE);
```

It works fine now.